# How to divide below class which have independent methods with each other?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have implemented a class including methods which is not supported by built-in Java. However, after some time, this class has become quite large.  Since it includes independent methods like `printMapContainer() and splitMapContainer`, I thought I should divide class into two or more different, logical, sub classes and add some hierarchy. But, I don't know how to split below class because they don't fit to an `inheritance` sort of problem. How should I logically divide this class which has independent methods with each other so that I can put more methods to a new hierarchy without losing code quality?  (30 methods in one class, so awkward, is it not?)

```
 HashMapHelper

      mergeHashMaps.java // merge more than one hash maps into one 
      printHashMap.java  // print key,value pair in desired format to console
      formHashMap.java   // form existing hash map into new format
      splitHashMap.java  // split hash map into more same size chunks
      isEqual.java       // is two hash map contain same pair
      removeALL.java     // remove all key from hash map
      updateKeyALL.java  // update hash map with new key set
```

Each method has more than one helper method in order to obey 24-line-for-each-method rule. Therefore, in only one class, I have nearly 20 methods. I just want to put hierarchy to this class and then use, for example; maybe like, `HashMapHelper hMH = new BasicHashMapMethods();`.

Comment: It sounds like all the methods are helper methods for hashmaps. In that case, I would just leave them all in the same class. As a side note, 24 lines per method isn't a set rule, it is just a good guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it appears that all methods of your class are stateless. In this case, the class should be a non-instantiable helper class, with all its methods declared `static`. Inheriting this class is not a good idea, because all its functionality is potentially useful. If you find yourself adding methods geared toward different collections to the same class, you may want to split the class into, say, `HashMapHelper` and a `MapHelper`, with `HashMapHelper` using methods of `MapHelper` as needed.

Classes with 30+ helper methods are *not* uncommon in Java. For an example of a class that has similar functionality look at the [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class: it has 50+ methods, all of which are useful for manipulating Java collections.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance should not be used just for the sake of code re-use. Use composition or delegation instead.

If you can't use inheritance then don't. Before using Inheritance,  ask yourself whether **LSP** is followed or violated?

**Liskov's Substitution Principle (LSP)** - "Each derived class should be properly substitutable to its base class"

Also, you may need to do **Extract class** refactoring. Then you will have some more classes with some methods. I'm suggesting you only five **Refactorings** because they fits well in this situation.

- Move Method
- Move Field (if your system has fields)
- Extract class
- Extract Superclass
- Extract Subclass

**Refactoring** is restructuring your code changing its internal structure without changing observable behaviour. Before writing some code keep **SOLID Principles** in mind. That will help you a lot to write better code.